# How do I group by date in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm trying to find a query in Cassandra cql to group by date. I have "date" datatype where the date is like: "mm-dd-yyyy". I'm just trying to extract the year and then group by. How to achieve that?

```
SELECT sum(amount) FROM data WHERE date = 'yyyy'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do a partial filter with just the year on a column of type `date`. It is an invalid query in Cassandra.

The [CQL `date` type](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/cql/types.html#dates) is encoded as a 32-bit integer that represents the days since epoch (Jan 1, 1970).

If you need to filter based on year the you will need to add a column to your table like in this example:

```
CREATE TABLE movies (
    movie_title text,
    release_year int,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY ((movie_title, release_year))
)
```

Here's an example for retrieving information about a movie:

```
SELECT ... FROM movies WHERE movie_title = ? AND release_year = ?
```